# Bootstrap datepicker, disable dates - view only mode possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm loading a selection of dates into bootstrap datepicker for the user to view. Currently they can click on a highlighted date but it clears all the dates that are preloaded.

I don't want them to be able to click on any dates, just view the different month pages of dates. How can I do this?

this is how I setup datepicker and load the dates;

```
              $('.datepickera').datepicker({
                  format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
                  multidate: false


              });
              $.extend($.datepicker,{_checkOffset:function(inst,offset,isFixed){return offset}});
              $(".datepickera").data("datepicker").setDates($('#mydates').data('dates'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can make the datepicker unselectable by using the `daysOfWeekDisable` property like this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    });
```

`0` is Sunday and `6` is Saturday. This way a user cannot select any day but can view the entire calendar. [You can read more about it here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#defaultviewdate). Hope that helps.